# Using SELECT and concatenation MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_where

This works:

```
SELECT
    s.*,
    (SELECT ProductName
     FROM Products
     WHERE SupplierID = s.SupplierID LIMIT 1) AS ProductNames
FROM
    Suppliers s
```

I want to use something like this:

```
SELECT
    s.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(SELECT ProductName
                 FROM Products
                 WHERE SupplierID = s.SupplierID) AS ProductNames
FROM
    Suppliers s
```

Where each row of Suppliers is shown, even if ProductNames is empty but it gives an error.

Is something like that possible? I know that LEFT JOIN could also work.

Comment: This may be personal preference, but I strictly avoid the use of subqueries in `SELECT` clauses unless absolutely vital. I think a `LEFT JOIN` would be a far more appropriate solution. Do you already know how to write the query using `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: My actual query requires many joins. Usually I use a lot of inner joins but I want it to show even if the items in the joins aren't there. So I tried changing them all to left joins but it isn't working properly.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your `LEFT JOIN` query?

Comment: I've added it to my question

Comment: I've added another try - which gives an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_where

```
SELECT s.*,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ProductName) FROM Products WHERE SupplierID = s.SupplierID) AS ProductNames
FROM Suppliers s
```